# Can't make a GET Request with specific URL-PATH

Tags: api, http, url, curl, get

Im working with an API, where I need to GET a specific Invoice.

To get all Invoices, the Documentation of the Service says:

`https://api.domain.com/v1/Invoices` - This works like a charm.

So to get a specific Invoice, the Documentation says:

`https://api.domain.com/v1/Invoices({Id})` - Doesn't work.

I am working with curl, so my Code is:

`curl --header "Authorization:Bearer uh12iuh9ihihshu991u3"-X GET https://api.domain.com/v1/IncomingInvoices`

`uh12iuh9ihihshu991u3` is a Token.

I don't know how to get a specific Invoice, when `ID = 1`.

**I tried:**

```
- https://api.domain.com/v1/Invoices=1

- https://api.domain.com/v1/Invoices1
```

All are giving me Errors.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What are the errors you're seeing?

Comment: "The Ressource can not be found".

Comment: You can use Postman, it will give you more freedom for testing.

Comment: I am just guessing. You may try https://api.domain.com/v1/Invoices?Id=1

Comment: Try "https://api.domain.com/v1/Invoices(1)"

Comment: @JulianReschke Error:bash: Unexprected word '('

Comment: @J.Doe - you'll have to learn how to quote special characters on a Unix command line